# Client side ssl certificate using Zend_Http_Client

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, ssl-certificate

i've been trying to set up a secure communication using client side certificate between my client application and my server application.
I've set up a the configuration in my apache web server and both in my browser just to make sure that it works and it does.

i'm using zend framework 1.12, and according to the documentation on Zend website 
the following example should work:

```
$config = array( 'sslcert' => 'path/to/ca.crt', 'sslpassphrase' => 'p4ssw0rd');
$adapter = new Zend_Http_Adapter_Socket();
$adapter->setConfig($config);
$http_client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$http_client->setAdapter($adapter);
$http_client->setUri('https://somewhere.overtherainbow.com:1337/bluebird');
$http_client->request();
```

but everytime i just get the same exception

> Unable to Connect to ssl://somewhere.overtherainbow.com:1337

There is no doubt that i'm using the right certificate and passphrase and there is access to the remote machine 
so where could be the downfall ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple firewall issue - login to the server and stop iptables and then see if it connects. Or add an exception to the clients IP to access mysql. Also check :1337 is open

Comment: there is no network problem since i'm able to connect with my browser using the certificate
i suspect it has something to do with the certificate/ssl

Comment: have you tried $http_client->setUri('https://somewhere.overtherainbow.com/bluebird'); - without the port

Comment: using the port is crucial, whats more is that i'm able to see the TCP handshake happening on Wireshark.
but somthing with the ssl encryption layer failed for some reason..